# How to extract some information from an image in java?

Tags: java, image-processing

i want to extract some information from an image.

example if an image has some text like ADDRESS:INDIA

i want to find out text corresponding to ADDRESS and store it in my database
how can i achieve this?

i didn't get any information or help regarding this.

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is the text ADDRESS:INDIA in the picture? Like a text-image? Or did you mean EXIF data?

Comment: ADDRESS:INDIA is in the picture... and want to find out text corresponding to Address